# Google geocoder failing due to over_query_limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm filling four form fields using reverse geocoding. The form fills correctly but then I receive an error stating OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. On checking the JS console of chrome I see that five identical calls have been made before I received the error message. I'm unsure why my code is making several requests. Could someone please point out what I should change in my loops in the codeLatLng function. That's most likely where the problem is.

```
var geocoder;

function getCity() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
  }


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    //alert("Success funciton" + lat + " " + lng);
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)    
}

function errorFunction(){
    AppMobi.notification.alert("For the best user experience, please ensure your device GPS and geolocation settings are enabled.","Geolocation disabled","OK");
}

    function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    //alert("codeLatLng fn started");
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
     //alert(results[0].formatted_address) //Complete address
    $("#address1").val(results[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      alert("No results found. Please enter the data manually.");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status +".  Please enter the data manually." );
  }
});
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can't be all your code, because at the moment `getCity()` is not called, which means that `geocoder` is never defined and `geocoder.geocode()` will fail.

Comment: You might have to provide more code, a link to the page, or set up a jsFiddle page. I don't see a loop within the `codeLatLng` function. I can't see how the geocoder is getting called in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use of the Google Maps API Web Services is subject to specific limits on the amount of requests per day allowed.

OVER_QUERY_LIMIT is caused by this restriction.

Here you can find more information:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

You can try to wait over 2 seconds when google responds with this error, for example, with a setTimeout.

It could be that results[0].address_components[i] will be a reference to a function call.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I understand the restriction from google's end. I am unable to identify what in my code is causing multiple requests (I only want to make one request!).

After reading your comment, I tried commenting out the results[0].address_components[i] completely. Instead just entering in one long chunk of text as the address in a form field (ex: 123 Fake Ave., SomeCity, SomeState, SomeCountry). However, I still see the same error. :(..

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't see anything in your new code :( . I suggest to reduce all to a simple call to geocoder.geocode and isolate it from all other code. Could It be you have override some geocode function (variable)?