# Javascript fails when executing maps.google.Geocoder()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

My code fails when it tries to execute the google maps api: maps.google.Geocoder();

In the following code the second alert does not run:

```js
scope.locations = [];
alert('IGP scope.locations = '+scope.locations);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
alert('geocoder = ' + geocoder);
```

The Google maps api is included in my index.html file as follows:

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

<script src="lib/ion-google-place/ion-google-place.js"></script>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can find out why this is failing? The code works ok when run on a browser but fails when part of an ionic app running on a phone.

**UPDATE**

I have found the cause but have no idea why this is causing the problem. If I remove the following line from my index.html the google maps stuff works ok:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

My remaining problem though is that I need this line to solve a problem I have been having with logging in on Android phones! All very strange.

Comment: Where is the `<script>` tag in your page in relation to your script (i.e. is *must* be before your `var geocoder = ...` script.)

Comment: You have `google.maps.Geocoder();` , isn't it `maps.google.Geocoder();`?

Comment: The 'geocoder =' is in the ion-google-place.js file which comes after the maps.googleapis.com script

Comment: sailens, according to the Google website it is google.maps.Geocoder.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for an answer to this as well!

Have attached to my Android device via the "chrome://inspect" option, and there's a script error:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at link (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ion-google-place/ion-google-place.js:17:40)
```

which is the line:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

(Note that I'm using the forked version: https://github.com/gfnork/ion-google-place which seems to be better maintained.

I'll update this once I've figured out the rest, but hope this helps in the mean time (I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment...)

-- UPDATE 1 --

In the network log, the following script is not getting loaded:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false
```

So, that would seem to be the root cause.  Perhaps it's a Cordova whitelisting issue?

-- UPDATE 2 - Solved --

So after spending hours trying various different Content Security Policy variations and variants on the script tag, it came down to an out of date version of the Android platform installed.

Try this:

1. Save your plugins with: "cordova plugin save"
2. Remove Android as a platform with: "ionic platform rm android" then add it back again with: "ionic platform add android"
3. Try rebuilding and running.

My android version in /platforms/platforms.json was 4.0 something, and it is now: {
    "android": "4.1.1"
}

My Content Security Policy is set to:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

And my script call is:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{API-KEY}}&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

Comment: Edward, thanks for that. If you look at the update to my question above you can see how I fixed the problem. I have no idea why that content security meta tag was causing the problem nor how I will manage without :)

Comment: This was a useful site for getting a minimum level project working so I could compare it. http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-geoloacation-api-with-google-maps-in-ionic-framework/1/

Comment: Thanks for that I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works, the error is somewhere else.

You can check out this as well : [Google geocoder failing due to over_query_limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574824/google-geocoder-failing-due-to-over-query-limit)

```js
//scope.locations = [];
//alert('IGP scope.locations = '+scope.locations);
console.log('test alert');//so snippet can run
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
console.log('geocoder = ' + geocoder);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, as mentioned in my question it works fine when run on a browser (just not when part of an app running on a mobile phone). What I was hoping for was some pointers as to why this might be failing and how to track down the problem.

Comment: Do you have console feedback?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to see the console log

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you did not included apikey as in the example:
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">

Comment: API keys are not supposed to be needed but I have tried with one anyway and still get the same problem

Comment: Right, actually you have not stated that you were running it on mobile, it is a huge difference from desktop, so next time it will help us to help you if you give more details. Cheers

Comment: Actually I did state in the question it works fine in a browser but not on an iPhone.